# Django Query distinct values works but i cant use the query result

Tags: python, django, django-views, distinct, django-queryset

I have a table column which some values are double or triple written. I want to have a distinct query.

I tried

```
staff = Staff.objects.all().values('person').distinct()
for k in staff:
     j = k.person
     print j,k
```

I get "dict object has not attribute as person" for k.person

And I get k gives me a result like

```
{'person': 778L}
{'person': 779L}
{'person': 780L}
{'person': 781L}
{'person': 782L}`
```

Do you know how can I get the person value?

Comment: "k" is a dict. Access by k['person']

Comment: Now there is `values_list()`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Its not problem with `distinct` but with `values()`. `values()` gives you dict of values you requested. And to get attribute from dict you can use `dict['attr_name']`.

So you can try this:

```
staff = Staff.objects.all().values('person').distinct()
for k in staff:
    j = k['person']
    print j,k
```

Answer (score 5):

@Rohan is right. `dict['attr_name']` will give you what you want.

```
staff = Staff.objects.all().values('person').distinct()
print staff.query

#it returns:
#SELECT DISTINCT "staff"."person" FROM "staff"
```

beside this if you use this [patch](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6422), you can achieve this as following structure:

```
staff = Staff.objects.all().distinct('person')
for pr in staff:
    print pr['person']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
query = Entity.objects.filter(field=x).order_by('field').distinct('field_name')

distinct('field_name') not supported? you can do the following.


----------


    query = Entity.objects.filter(field_name=value).order_by('field')

    copy1 = []

    copy2 = []
for data in query:
    if data.field_name not in copy1:
            copy1.append(data.field_name)
            copy2.append(data)


    query = copy2
```

Comment: # if field_name is a foreignkey, then use field_name.pk

Comment: Hi Sayeem! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be sure to read the guidelines - don't just provide code as an answer, tell us a bit about your solution!

Comment: Works probably great, but it will still load everything. It isn't optimized. So don't use this with great datasets.