# Use .distinct() with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, distinct

In order to work with `.distinct()` in django in knowing that we work with MySQL, is there an alternative to

```
In [48]: perc = Perception.objects.all()

In [49]: perc
Out[49]: <QuerySet [<Perception: Perception #0000001>, <Perception: Perception #0000002>, <Perception: Perception #0000003>, <Perception: Perception #0000004>]>

In [50]: perc.filter(loan__request__customer=205).distinct('loan__request__cust
    ...: omer__user__last_name')
Out[50]:
```

In fact, I read that "`.distinct([*fields])` only works in PostgresSQL" on the website [Django MySQL distinct query for getting multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402923/django-mysql-distinct-query-for-getting-multiple-values).  The issue is related to the line 50 which didn't return anything.

**Question :** Is there an alternative for `.distinct()` in Django when we work with MySQL?

Thanks!

**P.S.** Please tell me if the question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
Perception.objects.all().values_list('my_field', flat=True).distinct()
```

I haven't tested it, but give it a try and let me know.

Comment: What could I do if I have a specific user for `loan__request__customer`, e.g., `loan__request__customer = 205` ?

Comment: `Perception.objects.filter(loan__request__customer = 205).values_list('my_field', flat=True).distinct()` is that what you meant?