# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field when using values_list

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have encountered the error which I cannot solve after I read the django doc and django-rest-framework doc,even I read all the related question on stackoverflow,I still cannot solve it.

the full error message is as following:

```
AttributeError at /api/v1/task/target/subdomain/get_by_target/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `target_id` on serializer `TargetSubdomainSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `tuple` instance.
Original exception text was: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'target_id'.
```

I want to get the distinct result on my table, so I use django filter and distinct, when I just use the filter, the code runs correctly, but when I use filter and values_list at the same time, it runs into error.

the TargetSubdomain model is as following:

```
class TargetSubdomain(models.Model):
    target_id = models.IntegerField(help_text='目标ID')
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='域名')
    source = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text='子域名来源')

    created_at = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, help_text='创建时间')
    updated_at = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, help_text='更新时间')

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created_at = int(time.time())
        self.updated_at = int(time.time())
        super(TargetSubdomain, self).save()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'nw_target_subdomain'
```

the TargetSubdomainSerializer is as following:

```
class TargetSubdomainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TargetSubdomain
        fields = '__all__'
```

the TargetSubdomainViewSet is as following:

```
class TargetSubdomainViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TargetSubdomain.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = TargetSubdomainSerializer

    @action(methods=['GET'], detail=False, url_name='get_by_target')
    def get_by_target(self, request):
        target_id = request.GET.get('targetId')


        # queryset = TargetSubdomain.objects.filter(target_id=target_id).values_list('id', 'target_id', 'domain').distinct()
        queryset = TargetSubdomain.objects.filter(target_id=target_id)

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        response = {
            'results': serializer.data
        }

        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, headers=headers)
```

when the queryset from `queryset = TargetSubdomain.objects.filter(target_id=target_id)`, the code has no eror, but when I try to get the distinct result using `# queryset = TargetSubdomain.objects.filter(target_id=target_id).values_list('id', 'target_id', 'domain').distinct()`, it will raise the attribute error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `values_list` queryset behaves like a list of tuples and therefore each tuple doesn't have a `target_id` attribute. Why are you using a values_list in this case? If you are trying to just get a unqiue on those fields provided to the values_list you can use `distinct(*fields)`. Only works on PostgresSQL though. Otherwise, get them all as per your first queryset and then do the de-dupe in Python.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

```
def get_queryset(self):
    subdomains = TargetSubdomain.objects.filter(target_id=target_id)
    unique = {
        subdomain.domain:subdomain for subdomain in subdomains
    }
    return unique.values()
```

Comment: I want to use distinct so I use the values_list, because the sql `queryset = TargetSubdomain.objects.filter(target_id=target_id).values_list('id', 'target_id', 'domain').distinct() ` works in my other project, but in the project I am working, it report the attribute error.

Comment: Yes I know but your serializer cant serialize a values_list. So you'll have to use something different, hence I ask why you need it?

Comment: I am sorry,I can't tell you why.In my previous project, I need to get distinct result, so I search google, so etc, at the end, I find one way to get the distinct result which use the values_list and it works well, event I don't know why.I tried to debug the source, but I failed to explain why, sorry.

Comment: If you dont know why you need values_list, and you want distinct results just use `queryset = TargetSubdomain.objects.filter(target_id=target_id).distinct()`

Comment: I tried this, but  I want to get the distinct on the specified field.please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402923/django-mysql-distinct-query-for-getting-multiple-values, He used `values`, whether the result is correct, he can use `values`, but I can't use values.

Comment: 1) you're using values_list not values. 2) in your link hes not using drf to serialize that data. If your goal is to get the distinct on specified field then values or values_list wont help you. If you are lucky enough to be using postgres you can do 'distinct(field_name)' if not you will need to get the unique values in python. I can update my answer to show you how if you wish

Comment: please help me how can I get the distinct value on `domain` field, which result same as the raw sql `SELECT * FROM nw_target_subdomain WHERE target_id={target_id} GROUP BY domain`

Comment: First i need to know are you using PostgresSql database?

Comment: Unfortunately Django ORM doesn't support distinct on fields for mysql. You'll have to do it in Python. I've updated my answer to show you how.