# Django filter() by ForeignKey returns incorrect queryset

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, orm

I have two models, `Product` model connects to `ProductGroup` by `ForeignKey` and a `Product` model also has a `ForeignKey` field named `shop`:

```
class ProductGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    vat_rate = models.ForeignKey(VatRate, verbose_name="VAT in percent", related_name='product_group_vat_rates',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_shop")
    product_group = models.ForeignKey(ProductGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    cost_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    stock_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True,
                                       help_text=_('Product amount in stock'))
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Let's assume, I have two `Product` instances, connected to particular shop, and one `ProductGroup`, that connected to this two `Product` instances

So now I want to get all `ProductGroup` instances, that relate to particular `shop` instance.

What I do:

```
product_group_list = ProductGroup.objects.filter(product__shop=shop_inst)
```

What I think I will get:

```
<QuerySet [<ProductGroup: Product Group test product group>]>
```

But, unfortunately, I get this:

```
<QuerySet [<ProductGroup: Product Group test product group>, <ProductGroup: Product Group test product group>]>
```

So it returns to me queryset of these two `ProductGroup` instances connected to `Product` instances.

How can I improve my query to DB to get only ONE `ProductGroup` instance, that connected to this shop? (Because there's only one record in DB with `ProductGroup`)

Comment: Are you using PostgresSQL or MySQL? ```.distinct()``` only works in PostgresSQL.

Comment: I’m using MySQL

Comment: sorry -- I think my comment was misleading. In the past I had thought distinct didn't work on MySQL (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402923/django-mysql-distinct-query-for-getting-multiple-values). Maybe I was misreading something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the *same* `ProductCategory` multiple times due to JOINing, you can use `.distinct()`:

```
product_group_list = ProductGroup.objects.filter(product__shop=shop_inst).distinct()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct` on your query to eliminate duplicates

[`distinct(*fields)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

> Returns a new QuerySet that uses SELECT DISTINCT in its SQL query.
>   This eliminates duplicate rows from the query results.
>
> By default, a QuerySet will not eliminate duplicate rows. In practice,
>   this is rarely a problem, because simple queries such as
>   Blog.objects.all() don’t introduce the possibility of duplicate result
>   rows. However, if your **query spans multiple tables**, it’s **possible to**
>   **get duplicate results** when a QuerySet is evaluated. That’s when you’d
>   use distinct().

```
product_group_list = ProductGroup.objects.filter(product__shop=shop_inst).distinct()
```