# Django - How to QuerySet Distinct on field?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a Model like below (Mysql). For some reasons, we have duplicated data on this Table. I tried to get distinct records based on Phone, but I couldn't make it done.
Can someone help me out, many thanks in advance.

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, default='')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey('generals.Product', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Comment: queryset = Sale.objects.all().distinct('phone')...   what did you try?

Comment: Just like yours, and the error was raised: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Comment: please see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12403362/8243936)

Comment: distinct('value') doesnt work with mysql...   can you try this: queryset = Sale.objects.values('phone').distinct()

Comment: Then I only got the phone list, I tried to get the full-record instead with only single line of code as well

Comment: But i dont understand, even if you run distinct on phone... suppose phone1 = 2345  name1 = abc; phone2= 2345  name2= dcf.. in this case what do you expect your query to return?

Comment: hello @Tringuyenminh just curious... did you find a solution?