# DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am using distinct to get the distinct latest values but it is giving me an error:

> DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

**`views.py`**

```
class ReportView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'admin/clock/report.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ReportView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['reports'] =  TimesheetEntry.objects.filter(
                                  timesheet_jobs__job_company = self.request.user.userprofile.user_company,
                              ).distinct('timesheet_users')
        return context
```

Basically I want to query on `TimesheetEntry` model where there will be lot of entries of `user` which is a foreign key in `User` in-built model.

So I want to query with distinct user so that latest entry of the user will be displayed. It is very important for me to get the latest entry of user.

**`models.py`**

```
class TimesheetEntry(models.Model):
    timesheet_users = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='timesheet_users')
    timesheet_jobs = models.ForeignKey(Jobs, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='timesheet_jobs')
    timesheet_clock_in_date = models.DateField()
    timesheet_clock_in_time = models.TimeField()
```

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: @SergeyPugach I am using MySQL.

Comment: It won't work for MySQL, it works for PostgreSQL only.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`distinct('field_name')` is not supported in MySQL. It only support `distinct()`. `distinct('field_name')` will only work on **PostgresSQL**. For more details, please check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).

**Examples (those after the first will only work on PostgreSQL):**(*Copy Pasted from Documentation:*)

```
>>> Author.objects.distinct() 
   [...]

>>> Entry.objects.order_by('pub_date').distinct('pub_date')
   [...]

>>> Entry.objects.order_by('blog').distinct('blog')
   [...]

>>> Entry.objects.order_by('author', 'pub_date').distinct('author', 'pub_date')
   [...]

>>> Entry.objects.order_by('blog__name', 'mod_date').distinct('blog__name', 'mod_date')
   [...]

>>> Entry.objects.order_by('author', 'pub_date').distinct('author')
   [...]
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i query for MySQL?

Comment: You can look into this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382232/django-query-distinct-values-works-but-i-cant-use-the-query-result

Answer (score -1):

May you should this one

```
>>> queryset = TimesheetEntry.objects.distinct()
>>> context['reports'] = queryset .filter(timesheet_jobs__job_company = self.request.user.userprofile.user_company, )
```