# Django : DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Tags: django

How to fix DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend in django?

```
total = grade.objects.values('Grading_Categories').annotate(Average= Avg('Average')).filter(Teacher = m.id).distinct('Grading_Categories')
```

this is my model.py

```
class finalrating(models.Model):
    Teacher = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True, blank=True)
    Subjects = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrolledSubject, related_name='+',
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Average = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request, blank=True)
```

my problem is from this line

```
total = grade.objects.values('Grading_Categories').annotate(Average= Avg('Average')).filter(Teacher = m.id).distinct('Grading_Categories')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54249017/distinct-on-fields-is-not-supported-by-this-database-backend)

Comment: mr @ArakkalAbu i think not because in my problem there is include the annotate to compute the final average

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: Postgres mr @ArakkalAbu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are trying to get a **GROUP BY** result, with distinct `Grading_Categories` values.

So, try this

```
total = grade.objects.values('Grading_Categories').annotate(Average=Avg('Average')).filter(Teacher=m.id).order_by('Grading_Categories')
```

Comment: i have an error @ArakkaiAbo when i copy your answer """"Avg does not allow distinct."""""