# "Simple Dynamic" Dropdown menu in django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

First, I am quite new with django...
I am trying to add a dropdown menu of available distinct Users (by name and coming from my db "dynamically") in a form.

I am using django 2.2.6.

```
# MyCustomForm
class DetailedReportForm(forms.Form):
    AVAILABLE_USERS = MyUserModel.objects.order_by().values_list('name').distinct()
    selected_date = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'], required=True, widget=DateInput())
    selected_user = forms.CharField(label="Select a user", widget=forms.Select(choices=AVAILABLE_USERS))

# MyModel
class MyUserModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', unique=True, max_length=90)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

The issue I am facing is my queryset is not working (not sure why) as it is giving me the following: `not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

I tried to google it but still not very clear to me what this error message means.

Can someone please explain what this django error means so I can fix it and include the dropdown list in my form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `choices` argument expecting list of tuples like this: `[(1, "one"), (2, "two")]`. First element in tuple actual value to store in DB, second is human readable representation.

But actually in your case you can just use [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) instead:

```
class DetailedReportForm(forms.Form):
    AVAILABLE_USERS = MyUserModel.objects.order_by().values_list('name').distinct()
    selected_date = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'], required=True, widget=DateInput())
    selected_user = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Select a user", queryset=MyUserModel.objects.order_by().distinct("name"))
```

Otherwise list of available options wiil not updated dynamically, since code inside form class running only once on django starting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, for some reason. I cannot distinct on field when the backend is MySQL. So I had to replace your ```dictinct("name")``` to be distinct() [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54249017/distinct-on-fields-is-not-supported-by-this-database-backend)

Comment: @WilliamW yep, unfortunatelly distinct by field only work on PostgreSQL now.