# How to distinct a specified field in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm working with `django` and `mysql`.

Say there's a table as below:

```
class OrderInfo(models.Model):
    gg_account_id = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    order_status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    gg_status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    uid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'order_info'
```

And data saved in it are:

```
id  gg_account_id order_status  gg_status   uid 
1   6270491342       2            0          1
2    12321323        2            0          34
3    12321323        2            0          34
4    55551233        1            0          54 
5    55551233        2            0          54
6    55551233        2            0          54
7    55551233        2            0          54
```

If there are more than one data with same `gg_account_id`  I want to get only one of them. My expected output should be like :

```
1   6270491342          1
2    12321323           34
5    55551233           54
```

and here's my trial with orm query:

```
recharge_account_list = OrderInfo.objects.\
                                filter(order_status=2, gg_status=0).\
                                distinct("gg_account_id").\
                                values_list("gg_account_id", "uid", "id")

print(recharge_account_list)
```

But I got error always

```
  File "D:\virtual\Envs\smb_middle_server\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\operations.py", line 171, in distinct
_sql
    raise NotSupportedError('DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend')
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend
```

How can I get expected result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1: use forloop

```
gg_account_ids = set()
recharge_accounts = []
for i in recharge_account_list:
    if i[0] not in gg_account_ids:
        gg_account_ids.add(i[0])
        recharge_accounts.append(i)
recharge_account_list = recharge_accounts
```

Solution 2: use raw SQL

```
recharge_account_list = OrderInfo.objects.raw('SELECT ... FROM Order_info GROUP BY ...')
```

Comment: Can u provide me a valid sql here with which I can get my expected result ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It can be observed that you are using `mysql` as a database.
However, `MySQL` does not support distinct on the field. I mean by `distinct('field_name')` it only supports generic distinct So you can do only `distinct()` operation but not on specific fields.

[distinct documentation Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54249017/distinct-on-fields-is-not-supported-by-this-database-backend)

Furthermore, you can achieve that by using group by specific fields.

[Distinct with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382232/django-query-distinct-values-works-but-i-cant-use-the-query-result)

Comment: Can you give a advice which can get my expected result. Thanks